# Magento - Can't reach shopping cart - redirect straight to checkout

Tags: checkout, magento-1.9, shopping-cart

I have issues with my magento. I can't reach shopping cart page because it redirects to checkout page every time.
I'm using custom template, minimum order amount and built in checkout page.
It was working until I transfered website to another domain.

Does anyone know what to do?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch your Magento on default template and try to check it, if all will work properly, then find issue in theme (for example try to **grep** your theme for matches of old domain).

If it won't help you. Check, are there custom modules which affects Mage_Checkout or Mage_Sales. Try to check without these modules.

Comment: Thank you for you response. It isn't manner of the template. How can I easily find out which modules affect those core functions?

Comment: A lot of f words. I've been crying for last week that I have this issue and there is function in ajax cart module "Disable shopping cart" and I had somehow "Yes". I'm so stupid. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @sidlo : You should post it as an answer and accept it rather putting it as comment here

Comment: For future, you can try to find occurrences  '<rewrite>' in app/code/local or app/code/community in xml files. It will help you to found modules which affect core. Also, you can look in app/code/local/Mage (if exists) or app/code/local/Enterprise (if exists).

Comment: Thank you for advice. I'll keep it in my mind, notebook more than mind, because it'll help.

Answer (score 0):

What checkout are you using? Some checkouts have an option in System > Configuration 
I know this is definitely true for Firecheckout and a couple of the onepage checkout modules

I'd also check if your domain name was hardcoded into the custom template anywhere

Apart from that I presume you have refreshed magento and browser cache?

Comment: I've found it already. It was ajax procart where was shopping cart disabled.